# Configuratión mcp 3208 en raspberry pi 3 with spi

Tags: pi-3, python

I have a problem in the configuration of the A / D converter I am working with the Pi 3B +, in case the problem is that I do not know if the configuration is ok, since it only throws a zero value corresponding to the signal of a sensor UV radiation. This is the configuration that I am giving to the converter from the raspberry pi. This is all the code I am using, additionally there are some LEDs that indicate the outputs but these do not give problem, if the sensor signal is being produced but I think the mcp does not read the data and does not transmit it to the raspberry

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# GUVA-S12SD via MCP3008 (A/D converter)

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #importamos la libreria gpio de la raspberry pi
# y le colocamos un alias con el (as)

from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
import spidev
import time
import os

GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)#tome en cuenta la numeracion que tiene el pin en si
#GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)... Toma en cuenta la nomenclatura o numeracion de los
#pines del 1 al 40


spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

def ReadChannel(channel):
        adc = spi.xfer2([6,0,0])
        data = ((adc[1]&5) << 8) + adc[2]
        return data

def ConvertVolts(data,place):
       #volts = (data * 3.3)/float(1023) 
        volts = (data * float (4096))/3.28
        volts = round(volts,place)
        volts = int(volts * 1000)
        return volts

bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
bestand.write("\n=================================================\n")
bestand.write("  UV-Index meting start op ")
bestand.write(now.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S"))
bestand.write("\n=================================================")
bestand.write("\n")
bestand.close()

uv = 0

#Meetresolutie (sec)
delay = 1

while True:
        uv_value = ReadChannel(uv)
        uv_volts = ConvertVolts(uv_value,8)

        os.system("clear")
        localtime = time.asctime( time.localtime(time.time()) )

        #Maak UV-log
#       uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
#       bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
#       bestand.write(localtime)
#       bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV" + " \n")
#       bestand.close()

        print("\033[1;32m   Siste. de Monit. de Radiacion UV\033[1;m")
        print ("----------------------------")
        print (" "),localtime
        print ("----------------------------")
        print("   Voltage del Sensor es: {} mV".format(uv_volts))
#       print("    Indice-UV:"),

        if 0 <= uv_volts <= 50:
                print ('   Indice-UV: ~0 (No hay riesgo)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 0 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 51 <= uv_volts <= 226:
                print ('   Indice-UV: <1 (Bajo)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = <1 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 227 <= uv_volts <= 317:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 1 (Bajo)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","w")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 1 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 318 <= uv_volts <= 407:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 2 (Bajo)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 2 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(5,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(5,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 408 <= uv_volts <= 502:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 3 (Moderado)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " UV-index = 3 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(6,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 503 <= uv_volts <= 603:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 4 (Moderado)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 4 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(6,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 606 <= uv_volts <= 695:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 5 (Moderado)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 5 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(6,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(6,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(6,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 696 <= uv_volts <= 794:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 6 (Alto)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 6 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(13,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 795 <= uv_volts <= 880:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 7 (Alto)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 7 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(13,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(13,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(13,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 881 <= uv_volts <= 975:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 8 (Muy Alto)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","a")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 8 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(19,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 976 <= uv_volts <= 1078:
                print ('   Indice-UV:  (Muy Alto)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","w")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 9 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(19,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if 1079 <= uv_volts <= 1169:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 10 (Muy Alto)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","w")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 10 \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(19,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(19,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(19,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)
        if uv_volts >= 1170:
                print ('   Indice-UV: 11+ (Extremo)')
                uv_voltsa = str(int(uv_volts))
                bestand = open("/home/pi/my_python/mcp3008/UV-data.log","w")
                bestand.write(localtime)
                bestand.write(" --> "+ uv_voltsa + " mV:" + " Indice-UV = 11+ \n")
                bestand.close()
                GPIO.setup(26,GPIO.OUT)
                #colores verde(2.2k), amarillo(2.2k), naranja (415 h), rojo (560 h), violeta (415 h)
                GPIO.output(26,GPIO.HIGH)
                #GPIO.output(21,True)
                time.sleep(1)
                GPIO.output(26,GPIO.LOW)
                time.sleep(1)

        time.sleep(delay)
```

If someone can help me I would appreciate it very much.
[image]

Comment: A clear photo of the connections between the Pi and MCP3208 is almost essential if you want useful help.

Comment: if you look again and edit the publication with the information I have and request, in case you can help me I would be very grateful

Comment: Este post te puede ayudar a resolver el problema https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-adc/